# C++ Reading and Writing (same NAMED file)

Tags: c++, fstream

So... The idea is simple - opening and writing in the same file amout of wins(a) and loses(b) but i don't know how to do that. First problem i faced was: "Error with opening file just by string (s)", so i found a solution - using .c_str().
And now i see that there is no txt file that could save my data.
Any solution?
Thanks for help and Have a nice day!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

fstream in;

string s ;

char t;

int a, b;


int main(){

cout << "DECK NAME:";

cin >> s;

s += ".txt";

in.open(s.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out);

while(1){

 cout << "END: e" << endl;
 cin >> t;

 if(t == 'e'){
     in.open(s.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out);
     in << a << " " << b;
     in.close();
     return 0;
 }

 in >> a >> b;

 in.close();

 if(t == 'w') a++;
 else b++;

 cout << "Win: " << a << endl;

 cout << "Lost: " << b << endl;

 }
}
```

Comment: You can not read from and write to a same file.

Comment: Even if i close or remove it before writing?

Comment: At the same time.

Comment: You' re right, my bad -I only want to read and write in the same NAMED file

Comment: Please replace reading of the filenames from stdin by hardcoded values which lead to the problem you experience.

Comment: What do you mean by hardcoded value? Sorry, i am newbie ://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read and write from **one** file then you can use `fopen()` from `stdio.h` which would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

FILE *file;

int main()
{
    file = fopen("myfile.txt", "w+");
    fputs("test", file);
    std::cout << "Writing test to myfile.txt" << std::endl;
    fflush(file);
    rewind(file);
    char *myString = new char[5];
    fread(myString, 1, 5 * sizeof(char), file);
    std::cout << "Reading " << myString << " from myfile.txt" << std::endl;
}
```

You can read more about these functions here: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/